# Need help solving VBA.Array to acknowledge more than the first two groups

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-office, spreadsheet

We have what we refer to as an "Info" sheet as we progress through a job. We log specific pieces of information on this sheet, and would like for certain parties to be emailed whenever this information is filled out. The issue I'm facing is the information that is relevant comes in groups. It doesn't make sense for us to email an entire sheet or only the information that was edited, the group of whatever cell was edited need to be sent. I can only get this to work for the first two groups of cells (E16:E20 and E22:E25) when editing the other groups of cells, no email is sent.

```
Option Explicit

Private WorksheetNames As Variant
Private ValueRanges As Variant
Private OldValues As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    WorksheetNames = VBA.Array("Info", "Info")
    ValueRanges = VBA.Array("E16:E20", "E22:E25", "E51", "E52", "E53", "E54", "E67:E68", "E71", "E84:E87", "E88:E91", "E92:E95", "E96:E99", "E100:E103", "E104:E107", "E110:E112", "E113:E115", "E116", "E117:E119", "E120:E122", "E123", "E124", "E126", "E127", "E128")
    OldValues = GetValues
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ComposeAndSendMails
End Sub

Private Sub ComposeAndSendMails()
    
    Const COPY_COLUMNS As String = "A:E"
    Const ROW_DELIMITER As String = vbLf
    Const COL_DELIMITER As String = " - "
    Dim cIndices(): cIndices = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 5) ' skip column 'D'
    Dim Recipients(): Recipients = VBA.Array("E61", "E65", "E61,E63", "E61,E63", "E61,E63", "E61,E63", "E61,E63", "E61,E63", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "E61,E65", "K7,E61", "K7,E61", "K7,E61", "K7,E61", "K7,E61,E63")
    
    Dim rLen As Long: rLen = Len(ROW_DELIMITER)
    Dim cLen As Long: cLen = Len(COL_DELIMITER)
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(cIndices)
    
    Dim BaseName As String:
    With ThisWorkbook
        BaseName = Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".") - 1)
    End With
    
    Dim NewValues(): NewValues = GetValues
    If IsEmpty(GetValues) Then Exit Sub ' covered in 'GetValues'
    
    Dim bData(), n As Long, r As Long, c As Long, eCount As Long
    Dim Body As String, Recipient As String
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(NewValues)
        If IsColumnDifferent(OldValues(n), NewValues(n)) Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetNames(n))
                bData = .Range(ValueRanges(n)).EntireRow _
                    .Columns(COPY_COLUMNS).Value
                'Recipient = CStr(.Range(Recipients(n)).Value)
                    Dim cel As Range
                    Recipient = ""
                    For Each cel In .Range(Recipients(n))
                        Recipient = Recipient & ";" & CStr(cel)
                     Next
                        Recipient = Mid(Recipient, 2)
            End With
            For r = 1 To UBound(bData, 1)
                For c = 0 To cUpper
                    Body = Body & bData(r, cIndices(c)) & COL_DELIMITER
                Next c
                Body = Left(Body, Len(Body) - cLen)
                Body = Body & ROW_DELIMITER
            Next r
            Body = Left(Body, Len(Body) - rLen)
            SendMailSimple BaseName, Recipient, Body
            eCount = eCount + 1
            Body = ""
        End If
    Next n

    If eCount > 0 Then
        OldValues = NewValues
    End If
    
    MsgBox IIf(eCount = 0, "No", eCount) & " message" _
        & IIf(eCount = 1, "", "s") & " sent.", _
            IIf(eCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation)

End Sub

Private Function GetValues() As Variant
    
    If IsEmpty(WorksheetNames) Then
        MsgBox "The initial information got lost!", vbExclamation
        Exit Function
    End If
 
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(WorksheetNames)
    Dim Jag(): ReDim Jag(0 To UB)
    
    Dim n As Long
 
    For n = 0 To UB
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetNames(n)).Range(ValueRanges(n))
            Jag(n) = .Value
        End With
    Next n
        
    GetValues = Jag
 
End Function

Function IsColumnDifferent( _
    ByVal OldData As Variant, _
    ByVal NewData As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Long = 1) _
As Boolean
    Dim r As Long
    For r = LBound(OldData, 1) To UBound(OldData, 1)
        If CStr(OldData(r, ColumnIndex)) <> CStr(NewData(r, ColumnIndex)) Then
            IsColumnDifferent = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
End Function


Sub SendMailSimple( _
         ByVal Subject As String, _
         ByVal Recipient As String, _
         ByVal Body As String)
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .Subject = Subject
        .To = Recipient
        .Body = Body
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to modify the email recipients on the sheet so that when a group was sent to more than one person Visual Basic didn't have to process multiple cells. However, I found no success in this.

Comment: You have a couple options at least (without seeing your data). First, you can specifically target changes in any area by using the `Worksheet_Change` event. That could work with your `ValueRanges` array. Next, I've had issues when creating a global object (`ValueRanges` in your situation) that are intended to exist persistently, even though you've created a global. When I need this kind of data, I'll create a "hidden" worksheet and store all that data, then retrieve it when needed. This sets up the second possibility to focus your search for changes only where you've detected the change.

Comment: How would you suggest using Worksheet_Change to be as efficient as possible? I avoided using it so that it wouldn't take as long to edit the code if the groupings ever changed.

Comment: There are two values in `WorksheetNames`, which is the array you loop over using  `For n = 0 To UB`, so you're not going to access the "extra" values in `ValueRanges`.  You need to have the same number of sheet names as you have value addresses.

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the WorksheetNames, and it moved to a debug within the IsColumnDifferent function. I have reworked this function to handle one-dimensional and two-dimensional arrays and found success. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.